# Would like SQL query that pulls the last 7 days of table data with ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So I'm trying to pull the last seven days of table data using SQL within ASP. I think my syntax is incorrect

```
<%  
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql = "SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime is between '" & date & "' and '" & date 7  
& "'" 
rstest.Open sql, db
```

%>

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this. I will up vote ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= GETDATE()-7
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
```

But if you want absolute date (without caring about time:

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE())) - 7
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= DATEADD(d,-7,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE())))
```

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later:

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) - 7
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM DivisionNew where JMS_UpdateTime >= DATEADD(d,-7,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM DivisionNew 
WHERE JMS_UpdateTime >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This was a great help!